# Html and javascript cookie dying after browser window closes

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've added a darkmode setting to my website, and I made a cookie using javascript so it's saved for when you come back, everything works like a charm until you close the browser window.

```
var cookie = document.cookie = 'darkmode=false; SameSite=none; Secure';
```

Is there a way to make the cookie stay for as long as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add expires and/or max-age for the cookie.
Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) for more information.

```
var cookie = document.cookie = 'darkmode=false; max-age=31536000; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=none; Secure';
```